# self close tags those have to be closed by end tag like <div> </div>

Tags: html, tags

I was researching on `google map API`, and saw in [This link](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial) that there is a `<div>` tag that closed by itself...!!!

```
<div id="map-canvas"/>
```

***`and this is part of that page :`***

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
    <style type="text/css">
      html { height: 100% }
      body { height: 100%; margin: 0; padding: 0 }
      #map-canvas { height: 100% }
    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript"
      src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=API_KEY&sensor=SET_TO_TRUE_OR_FALSE">
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      function initialize() {
        var mapOptions = {
          center: new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644),
          zoom: 8
        };
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-canvas"),
            mapOptions);
      }
      google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="map-canvas"/>
  </body>
</html>
```

As much as I know, `<div>` tag have to close by end tag-->`</div>`
***`Would you tell me Why is that...?`***

**Thanks in Advance**

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I suppose that that is intentional. The tags are valid if they don't have any content in them.

Now take the case of `map-canvas`. It is obvious from the id that it'll be used to fill with the map.

So there shouldn't be anything in that div and a self closing tag is a way to ensure that.

Also note that when some content is injected, the `<tag />` will automatically become `<tag>some content</tag>`

Comment: The slash has no effect. You can see this e.g. by testing with `<body><div/>foo</body>` and setting a background on the `div` (or looking at the DOM in developer tools). It is parsed as `<body><div>foo</div></body>`, just as without the slash.

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela, the context in which I'm talking is to answer,OP's text clearly shows that there was nothing except `<div id="map-canvas">` Any way I removed the controversial part.

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela, however thanks for pointing out, so that I could help someone better next time.

Answer (score 1):

Every browser that supports XHTML (Firefox, Opera, Safari, IE9) supports self-closing syntax on every element.

`<div/>, <script/>, <br></br>` for this HTML 4.x doesn't have any concept of self closing tags. It is only valid in XHTML.

For html 5 these are the self closing tags:

```
<area />
<base />
<br />
<col />
<command />
<embed />
<hr />
<img />
<input />
<keygen />
<link />
<meta />
<param />
<source />
<track />
<wbr />
```

Answer (score 1):

Tags in xml that have a slash at the end are equivalent to the same without a slash. Without a  closing tag it will be interpreted as `<div></div>`

Answer (score 1):

It’s just sloppy coding that does not cause visible harm when the “self-closing” `<div id="map-canvas"/>` is the sole content of the `body` element. It is treated by browsers as if the slash `/` were not there, i.e. as an opening tag (only). They will then imply a closing tag when they encounter the end of the enclosing element, `</body>`. Things would be different if there were content after the “self-closing” tag.

It would be a real self-closing tag if it were used in XHTML in a document processed by XHTML rules, but it isn’t. The document lacks the required `xmlns` attribute, and it is practically certain that it is sent with the `text/html` content type, hence processed as HTML, not as XHTML.

[Appendix C](http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/#guidelines) of the XHTML 1.0 spec says: “Given an empty instance of an element whose content model is not `EMPTY` (for example, an empty title or paragraph) do not use the minimized form (e.g. use `<p> </p>` and not `<p />`).”

Answer (score 0):

You can close tags like that as long as they don't have any children

1-Must be closed with end tag since it has content

```
<div>
 <span></span>
</div>
```

2-Doesn't need an end tag since it doesn't contain any content

```
 <div/>
```